# Why is constructor invoked in assignment operation?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class MyString : public string {
public:
    MyString(const char* s) :string(s) {}
    MyString(const string& str) : string(str) { cout << "why is this line invoked?"; }
};
int main() {
    MyString s1("s1-"), s2("s2-");
    s2 = s1+s2; //I thought this line would be an assignment operation for s2. Not sure why constructor from line 7 is invoked?
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to inherit `MyString` class from `string class`. I wonder why `s2=s1+s2` would invoke constructor from `MyString`. Isn't it an assignment operation, instead of an initialization? Thank you!!

Comment: Evaluating `s2+s2` involves constructing s new object which is then assigned to `s2`

Comment: in general, when you add two things you get a new thing and this has to be constructed somehow

Comment: *I tried to inherit MyString class from string class* -- Why?  The `std::string` class is not designed to be inherited from.

Answer (score 8):

Because there's no overloaded binary `operator+` for your `MyString` class, the compiler must use the `std::string` overload for `operator+`.

The result of that is another `std::string` which is then used to construct a `MyString` object to be assigned to `s2`.